# Flask/NGINX 404s on only some POST requests

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask app served by Gunicorn using NGINX as a webserver. I only have two endpoints that have POST requests, a login and a submit post. The login works flawlessly however whenever I attempt to POST using the submit post endpoint, I receive a 404. My code works running on localhost without NGINX or Gunicorn and in order to detect that the request is POST vs GET I am using WTForms `validate_on_submit` method. The NGINX error and access logs don't show anything out of the ordinary.

Edit: Here is the code for the endpoints with post requests

New Post:

```
@app.route('/newpost', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = BlogForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #Omitted code for getting form data and creating form object
        try:
            #Omitted code for database actions
            return redirect(url_for('index', _external=True))
        except IntegrityError:
            flash("Error inserting into database")
            return('', 203)
    else:
        #Omitted some code for template rendering
        return render_template('new_post.html')
```

Login:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    userAuth = current_user.is_authenticated
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Login attempt logged")
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.userID.data).first()
        if user:
            checkPass = form.password.data.encode('utf-8')

            if bcrypt.checkpw(checkPass, user.password):
                user.authenticated = True
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
                return redirect(url_for('index', _external=True))
            else:
                form.errors['password'] = 'false'
        else:
            form.errors['username'] = 'false'

    else:
        return render_template('login.html',
                               title='Log In',
                               loggedIn=userAuth,
                               form=form)
```

Comment: Are you able to show the relevant code for the submit endpoint

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I've added the code. During my debugging I edited the endpoints to immediately return a string on POST to see if the issue was with the redirect or some database error but it still 404'd leading me to believe the error is with the POST request handling itself

Comment: Are you sure `url_for('index', _external=True)` is defined ? Do you have a route called `index` ?

Comment: Yes, the redirect to index from the login works perfectly, it is only the redirect from newpost that throws a 404 error (leading to my confusion, this is also why i ruled out NGINX configuration as a possible source of error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with NGINX after all, I fixed it by changing the ownership of /var/lib/nginx from the nginx user to the user running the Flask application. Prior to doing this AWS wasn't letting me upload files from my form in new_post.